# Why a Groovy List (of maps) arithmetic doesn't work as expected

Tags: groovy

I was trying to remove from a list of maps the elements that are present in another list. But found out that it doesn't work as i expected.
I can't understand the reason why.

```
def p1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
def p2 = [1,  3,  5]
assert p1[0] == p2[0]
assert p1[2] == p2[1]
assert p1[4] == p2[2]
assert [2,4] == p1-p2 // all ok

def q1 = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
def q2 = [[1],    [3],    [5]]
assert q1[0] == q2[0]
assert q1[2] == q2[1]
assert q1[4] == q2[2]
assert [[2], [4]] == q1-q2 // all ok

def t1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15]]
def t2 = [[1,2,3],          [7,8,9],             [13,14,15]]
assert t1[0] == t2[0]
assert t1[2] == t2[1]
assert t1[4] == t2[2]
assert [[4,5,6], [10,11,12]] == t1-t2 // all ok

def r1 = [[a:1, b:1], [a:2,b:2], [a:3,b:3],[a:4,b:4], [a:5,b:5]]
def r2 = [[a:1, b:1],            [a:3,b:3],           [a:5,b:5]]
assert r1[0] == r2[0]
assert r1[2] == r2[1]
assert r1[4] == r2[2]
assert [[a:2,b:2], [a:4,b:4]] == r1-r2 // this is what I expected but fails

assert [] == r1-r2 // this is totally unexpected but it's ok
```

I can't figure out why. Can someone shed some light on this.
Thanks

Comment: as you already stated it doesn't work how you expected, but you forgot to tell us what you expected (wanted to do). Do you get any errors along with unexpected behaviour?

Comment: I expected that r1-r2 would be [[a:2,b:2], [a:4,b:4]]

Comment: works for me, using groovysh in groovy 2.4.4. i can't reproduce any problem here.

Comment: Thanks it's true, it works ok on 2.4.4. Before I tested it on 2.3.8. So I guess there was a bug on earlier versions.